# Using DbContext to show data in wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I don't know how to use DbContext to show data in a Wpf Data Control as the ListView, ListBox or DataGrid.

I'm using the Database first approach, with VS2012.

I have a Database with one table (the simplest case).

[image]

Then I added an ADO Net Entity Data Model, it added several classes to my project, among them is OneTableEntities : DbContext:

[image]

Now I have a ListBox in a Wpf Window, what do I bind the listbox.ItemsSource to? I tried "listBox.ItemsSource = context.MyTables;" but I get this error:

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is
>   not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by
>   calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind
>   to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().

Where is that Load operation?, How can I populate a local store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error message says, you cannot bind control to query. Use [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute database query and save results to in-memory collection. Then you will be able to bind this collection to listbox:

```
listBox.ItemsSource = context.MyTables.ToList();
```

Another option you can find directly in error message:

```
context.MyTables.Load(); 
listBox.ItemsSource = context.MyTables.Local;
```